# SQL Server. Merge two select statements with inner joins each one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In advance sorry if my question is repeated or similar to another, I've alreay checked another posts similar to this but I can't get it right. So, here is my question. I have the next two select statements, and I have trouble in placing correctly the second query inside the first, I have tried putting inside the select, after the joins, and it'd be awesome if you could help me or give and advice.

```
select distinct 
    movements.date, movements.productcode, 
    products.productname,
    clasification.family, 
    clients.clientname, clients.clientcode,
    movements.quantity, movements.price, 
    movements.credit, movements.total,
    movements.exchange, movements.state, movements.city
from 
    invoices.movements
inner join 
    invoices.products on invoices.movements.idproduct = invoices.products.idproduct
left outer join 
    invoices.documents on invoices.movements.iddocument = invoices.documents.iddocument
inner join 
    invoices.coins on invoices.documents.idcoin = invoices.coins.idcoin
inner join 
    invoices.address on invoices.address.iddocument = invoices.documents.iddocument
inner join 
    invoices.clasifications on invoices.clasifications.family = 'aspen'
inner join 
    invoices.clients on invoices.documents.idclient = invoices.clients.idclient
```

This is the result I get from this query:

```
+----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+--------+----------+------+-----+--------+-----+----+
|date|product_code|product_name|client_name|client_code|invoice_reference|quantity|unit_price|credit|total|exchange|state|city|
+----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+--------+----------+------+-----+--------+-----+----+
```

But I also want to add two more columns, one for the client's clasification, where I can get if the client is **final user**, **installer**, **producer**, etc., here's the query that gives me that.

```
select 
    invoices.classifications.classification_value, 
    client_name, client_code 
from 
    invoices.clients
inner join 
    invoices.classifications on invoices.classifications.cid_classification = invoices.clients.cid_clasifclient1
inner join 
    invoices.documents on invoices.documents.cid_client = invoices.clients.cid_client
```

and the second column is the invoice series, I need to merge to columns into one, but it doesn't return any value when I add it to the first query.

```
select 
    convert(varchar(20), documents_series) + '' +
         convert(varchar(6), document_number) as invoice_series 
from 
    invoices.documents
```

So I'd really love if you could help me, and sorry if I'm not very good ad SQL.

Comment: it's quite painful to see the script but would be handy to see the structure however i can initially suggest to use APPLY... Outer apply (similar to outer join) or Cross Apply (similar to inner join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems like the connecting link is the *clients* table mainly between *idclient* and *cid_client* fields suggesting a primary/foreign key pair (or one-to-many join table), consider using last queries as a derived table in first query joined on these two fields. Also, try using [table aliases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx) as shown below to cut down repetitiously long table names:

```
select distinct m.date, m.productcode, p.productname
      , f.family, cl.clientname, cl.clientcode
      , m.quantity, m.price, m.credit, m.total 
      , m.exchange,m.state, m.city
      , sub.clasification_value, sub.invoice_series

from invoices.movements m    
inner join invoices.products p
   on m.idproduct = p.idproduct
left outer join invoices.documents d
   on m.iddocument = d.iddocument
inner join invoices.coins c
   on d.idcoin = c.idcoin
inner join invoices.address a
   on a.iddocument = d.iddocument
inner join invoices.clasifications f
   on f.family='aspen'
inner join invoices.clients cl
  on d.idclient = cl.idclient

inner join 
   (select subcl.idclient, subf.clasification_value
           , subcl.client_name, subcl.client_code 
           , convert(varchar(20), subd.documents_series)+''+
             convert(varchar(6), subd.document_number) as invoice_series
    from invoices.clients subcl
    inner join invoices.clasifications subf
      on subf.cid_clasification = cl.cid_clasifclient1
    inner join invoices.documents subd
      on subd.cid_client = cl.cid_client) As sub

  on sub.idclient = cl.idclient
```

Alternatively with a CTE instead of derived table:

```
with sub as
(
  select subcl.idclient, subf.clasification_value
         , subcl.client_name, subcl.client_code 
         , convert(varchar(20), subd.documents_series)+''+
           convert(varchar(6), subd.document_number) as invoice_series
  from invoices.clients subcl
  inner join invoices.clasifications subf
    on subf.cid_clasification = cl.cid_clasifclient1
  inner join invoices.documents subd
    on subd.cid_client = cl.cid_client
)

select distinct m.date, m.productcode, p.productname
      , f.family, cl.clientname, cl.clientcode
      , m.quantity, m.price, m.credit, m.total 
      , m.exchange,m.state, m.city
      , sub.clasification_value, sub.invoice_series

from invoices.movements m    
inner join invoices.products p
   on m.idproduct = p.idproduct
left outer join invoices.documents d
   on m.iddocument = d.iddocument
inner join invoices.coins c
   on d.idcoin = c.idcoin
inner join invoices.address a
   on a.iddocument = d.iddocument
inner join invoices.clasifications f
   on f.family='aspen'
inner join invoices.clients cl
  on d.idclient = cl.idclient
inner join sub
  on sub.idclient = cl.idclient
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help (: this fixed my issue. c: